# json iteration in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json

```
{
    "3": {
        "builderName": "All Branches",
        "currentStep": {
            "eta": 46.228333592710214,
            "expectations": [
                [
                    "output",
                    1519065,
                    1565397.0
                ]
            ],
```

I want to get keys and values from currentStep. Like eta and expectations.

```
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    $.each(value.currentStep, function (key, value) {
       console.log(value.eta); // this returns undefined            
    });
});
```

Comment: So you have a JSON string? Or an actually javscript object?

Comment: You are looping over the properties of `currentStep` – so `eta`, `expectations`, etc. Those do not have `eta` properties themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the key and value.

```
$.each(json, function (key, value) {
    $.each(value.currentStep, function (key, value) {
       console.log(key + " : " + value);            
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n3Y9T/)

Comment: But what if I only want the key and value of "eta" ?

Comment: The first iteration of the each you have the key and value of eta. Just use a simple if statement to test if it is eta and and do whatever you need to do with the value.

Answer (score 1):

This will log the keys/values of currentStep:

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value.currentStep, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key, value);
    });
});
```